# Azure Function Execution Timeout Expired

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I'm using a Logic App where the workflow calls at a certain point an Azure Function using the `Webhook URL` (as a workaround to Azure Functions Durable).

The goal of this function is to insert/update data into an Azure SQL Database with a SQL request

```
 "MERGE INTO...USING...WHEN NOT MATCHED...WHEN MATCHED AND...".
```

In the logs of the Azure Function, i could see it failed and it seems to run 4 times (maybe due to the supposed Timeout, I don't know), but I don't understand since I increased the CommandTimeout to 50minutes and I set 1Hour to the Timeout of the action "Launch Webhook" in the LogicApp :S Here's the sample of the exception logged in the Azure Function :

> Exception while executing function: XmlImport_DoWork
>       Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: XmlImport_DoWork ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>       The statement has been terminated. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : The wait operation timed out

The table actually have around 250,000 lines and it seems to be good when I launch the LogicApp (and so the Azure Function) to a table which is almost empty !

Any ideas about what's going on and how to fix it ? I tried to look at the "Query Performance Insight" in Azure SQL database component but there are nothing in "Recommendations" section

The Function App where are stored my Azure Functions is using an App Service Plan.
BTW the XML file I was trying to import in DB has a size of 20M but I tried with a lighter XML (9M) but it didn't work either

Comment: Perhaps you could use Azure Automation instead, which does not have this limitation. Is this loading Blob > SQL Azure?

Comment: Logic App run the Azure Function after creating a blob in a Storage Account yes

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what the logic app actually does, and whether it is suitable to build on a different platform (Maybe Azure Data Factory or Azure Automation) which does not have the constraints of logic apps.

Comment: I understand ;) Well the Logic App get the XML file from a SFTP Server --> Then it creates a blob in a StorageAccount --> Then it launches the Azure Function by calling its Webhook URL --> At the end of the process the latter should call the CallbackUrl to tell him the job is done --> finally it deletes the files in the StorageAccount and in the SFTP Server

Comment: and the Azure function loads this XML file into a database? You can probably do that in Azure automation which does not have the timeout issue. I have certainly used Azure Automation to import files into a database from blob storage, and Azure automation can be triggered from a web hook. Not sure about it triggering a web hook when complete but I'm sure it's possible

Comment: From the error message, it looks like the timeout is specifically a SQL timeout rather than an azure functions timeout. Functions does not generally force any timeouts when running in an app service plan.

Comment: Are you generating a massive single SQL statement based on the content of the blob? Have you tried breaking the process up into batches of SQL calls?

Comment: Well due to the situation in the project, I didn't try to break the process into batches of SQL calls :P But what do you mean by generating a massive single SQL statement ? Because the SQL statement is stored in a .SQL file and then the AzureFunction launch the merge by executing ExecuteNonQuery() on it

Comment: The relevant timeout for that error message is the `SqlCommand.CommandTimeout` property. But usually if you have to start changing timeouts, that implies other design problems (as Paul Batum is looking for).

Comment: Yes SqlCommand.CommandTimeout is the value I increased to 50minutes :P But I don't understand the file is only 20M and even if I try with a lighter XML it would be the same

Comment: Did you try not to use merge statements ? if the query is too complex the optimizer has trouble creating an optimal execution plan. If that happens, it is better to break your query up into multiple steps.

Comment: I agree with your point of view but the fact is the code was made by someone else and in the project we're in "code freeze" which means we cannot change it :P

Comment: It's nice to explain these things up front. Anyway.. you could extend your timeout to seven days and maybe it would work, but is that acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

**Azure Durable Function: V2 and .Net Core 2.2 - Timeout expired issue RESOLOVED**

The activity function 'A_ValidateAndImportData' failed: "**Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.**". See the function execution logs for additional details.

**Using DAPPER** to call SQL Server stored procedure: Dapper not honoring "Connection Timeout" Property in the connection string

Solution: Use a connection timeout parameter to provide "0"(ZERO or increase timeout according to your need) to solve this problem

**Example Code:**

```html
 public async Task<int> ValidateAndImportData(string connectionString, int param1,
            int databaseTimeOut = 0)
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                var param = new DynamicParameters();
                param.Add("@param1", param1);
                param.Add("@returnStatus", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);

                await connection.ExecuteAsync("[dbo].[ValidateAndImportData]", param,
                    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, commandTimeout: databaseTimeOut).ConfigureAwait(false);

                return param.Get<int>("returnStatus");
            }
        }
```