# SQL Query Wait Operation times out but only when running in an Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure Function App and Azure SQL DB.

In my Azure Function I query data (Using EF Core 3) and the following code:

```
var stuffIWant = dbContext.UsageCounts
                .Where(a=> a.Elo > 0 && a.Elo < 1300)
                .GroupBy(a => a.TheHash)
                .Select(b => new stuff { Hash = (long)b.Key, Count = b.Count() })
                .OrderByDescending(a => a.Count).Take(10).ToList();
```

I am getting a very high failure rate with an error that looks like:

```
[Error] Executed 'FunctionName' (Failed, Id=456456-0040-4349-81e3-54646546, Duration=30220ms)The wait operation timed out.
```

The exception:

```
[Error] Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

When I execute the function it sometimes (rarely) works fine and is able to make 8 queries like this (with the bounds for Elo changing) and each takes <200ms to complete.

I can also run this in a Sandbox project on my local machine, connecting to the same Azure DB using EF with the same model and can run it hundreds of times without ever timing out, each query taking <200ms to complete.

When the Azure function does work it always goes through each of the 8 queries and returns the data, when it doesn't work it always fails at the first query.

I added a "test" query to my function:

```
var test = dbContext.UsageCounts.Where(a => a.Elo > 2200).Take(10).ToList();
```

This happens before my failing query, and always succeeds.

Why is my function timing out most of the time when this query is nowhere near the execution time limit?

My database is not set to auto-pause.
My compute and IO utilization is under 20%

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this `[Error] Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.`, you can try following ways:

- In Tools->Options->Query Execution->SQL Server->General->Execution time-out. Set the time-out to more than 30 seconds or 0 to wait for the indefinite time.
- Check connection string, e.g. `connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=LMS;User ID=test;Password=test@123"`

You can refer to [The wait operation timed out establishing a connection to SQL Server FROM Azure Function App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52012982/the-wait-operation-timed-out-establishing-a-connection-to-sql-server-from-azure), [Azure Function Execution Timeout Expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49288309/azure-function-execution-timeout-expired) and [Troubleshooting connectivity issues and other errors with Azure SQL Database and Azure SQL Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/troubleshoot-common-errors-issues?view=azuresql#steps-to-fix-common-connection-issues)